# Get location details using Android Management API

Tags: android, api, android-location, android-management-api

I'm new to Android Management API and I'm unable to figure out how to get the location details using Android Management API. I have tried updating policy as such :

```
 policy_json = '''
{
  "applications": [
  {
    "packageName": "com.google.samples.apps.iosched",
    "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
    "permissionGrants": [
    {
      "permission": "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
      "policy": "GRANT"
    }
  }
],
  "locationMode": "HIGH_ACCURACY"
}
'''
```

But I don't seem to have gotten the location details. Can anybody please help me through? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The value HIGH_ACCURACY is only available in Android 8 or below. If you are using Android 9 or above, you should use LOCATION_ENFORCED instead.

Additionally, please note that locationMode only works on company owned devices.

Please refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#locationmode) for more information.

Comment: hi @rsiason, thank you for the response. I am using a company-owned device but LocationMode is used only to turn the location on/Off, it does not get the actual location details of the device. I'm looking for a solution to get the current address/location of the device.